# How to force an exe file to return to command prompt after execution

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, x86, reverse-engineering, patch

I have a `.exe` file (ASM86) that compiles a `.asm` file to a `.obj` file.
I don't know how the file itself works since I only have the executable.
When I run it in command prompt though, it completes the task and does not return control to the command prompt window. I have to close that window and open a new command prompt to do other things.
Just out of curiosity, I wanted to know if there's any way to modify the `.exe` file, without affecting its function, to make it return to the prompt?

Comment: I think asm86.exe is a really really old assembler, which might not be fully compatible with today's operating systems. Why not use something modern like [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/)?

Comment: unfortunately, this is a school project and thats the tool they gave us :/
Is it possible to achieve the above?

Comment: Sure it's possible - but you don't want to do it! Would control-c or control-break help?

Comment: Nah it wont. by not wanting to do it i assume you mean that its pretty tedious and might mess up the file?

Comment: just checked for this online. im using dosbox (cos i have a 64 bit system and need to emulate a 32bit system). apparently dosbox does not support ctrl+break :/

Comment: If your `.exe` file does not function the way you want (doesn't return to OS), you can of course modify it to suit your needs. You need to know x86 assembly and be able to use disassembler and/or debugger. If your `.exe` file is for DOS, the sufficient sequence used to return to DOS is `mov ah,0x4c`; `int 0x21`. Can be encoded as `b4 4c cd 21`. You just need to find out where to write that in the `.exe`, so you need to reverse-engineer the `.exe` file. Regarding Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Break, I think it's possible that Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Break might not work if the program has crashed.

Comment: Rather than patching the executable, why won't you look up the docs for asm86? There might a quit command and/or a "quit once done" command line switch.